# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53: production

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I have tried everything, looked all over the web, someone please help.
Works fine locally but when trying to push it up to fortrabbit that i get this error message.
Spent hours on it, I think it has to do with the configuration of .env variables, Im not sure. Some one please help, cheers.

I have used laravel 5.1 and 5.2 and still getting the same error.

Comment: Please provide your code along with routes.

Comment: It might be due to permissions issue. Make sure storage directory is 777

Comment: I solved problem by changing session driver to memcached when deploying to host.

Comment: Something to do with nodes the customer service guy said

Comment: but thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by changing session driver to memcached when deploying to host.